# Open multiple windows with JavaScript -- is there a proper way to deal with pop-up blockers?

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a service that lists dozen of items with appropriate links to them and I wanted to see about adding a function that allows users to open all of these with a single click.

Currently its a simple `window.open` call with unique name but the browser pop-up blocker catch these and simply block the call for these (tho they do open the last one). Is there a way to hint to the browser that this is a legit call from a user without adding a lengthy explainer that the user will need to tell their pop-up blocker to pipe down before this would actually work?

Comment: you can manually set for that domain to not pop-up block.. but are you asking for a pop-up blocker **bypass**? if not, you can wait for the user to like click a button or something.. if your response is to that kind of interaction that works

Comment: simple way to do the latter part of my sentence is `someElement.addEventListener('click',()=>window.open(location.href))` to test it

Comment: Manually explaining to the user how to disable pop-up blocker on my domain is a painful process -- there are multiple steps in this config and it varies per browser. I was hoping for something simpler, thats why I'm asking if there is a hint or something like that to the browser itself.

Comment: like I said, it is seen as legit if you are responding to a click.. there may be other interactions that it activates to, but it doesn't call a `mouseover` a valid user interaction to open another tab

Comment: Well, thats what I do now and its definitely triggering popup blocker.

Comment: a window might also close if the browser just sees the source of the window.open as sus.. I gave the `location.href` example because it would open a tab on the same [cross origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#)

Comment: That doesn't look like it matters -- the windows on the same domain are also blocked and only the last one is open.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242701/discussion-between-the-bomb-squad-and-fixanoid).